# changing a png image from project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.5

I want to change a png image in my project, I deleted the first one, and add the new one, but the last one is shown.

I deleted the second one from project, and the original image is still shown. I look for the image in the project, and it is not there.

How can I delete the first one? I tried to clean the project, but the image continues there.

Comment: i tried this but still doesnt work!

Comment: then just close your Xcode and reset your simulator

Comment: I did this before asking, I restart the computer too, the solution was deleting the app and reinstall it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

- Removing the app from device / simulator?
- Closing `Xcode`?
- Rebooting your computer?
- Rebooting your device?
- Resetting the simulator?

Answer (score 1):

Try Product -> Clean; then Run the app once again.

If it isn't working, then close the Xcode and open again and Run.

Even the problem exists, then just reset your simulator(ResetContentsAndSettings) and Restarts the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Delete that build from your simulator first.

Then clean and build the project again.

It should work.